# Which part number goes to these LEGO wedge pieces?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I'm trying to identify these two parts, plus the color on the greenish one.

[image: White part]

[image: Green part]

Answer (score 9):

The white one appears in [51 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=43713&colorID=1&in=A). It is piece [#43713 "White Wedge 6 x 4 Triple Inverted Curved"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43713&idColor=1#T=C&C=1).

The second piece looks like its color is "sand green", which is color #151. It is part #47759 "Wedge 2 x 4 Triple", which appears in one set in sand green: 70840 "Welcome to Apocalypseburg!"

Comment: Thanks; I'm still trying to identify what piece # the green one is.

Answer (score 0):

I got it; it's actually LEGO Olive Green Wedge 2 x 4 Triple (47759).

Comment: On the picture that doesn't look like olive green. I would have said sand green like EL_DON did in his answer. (But colors can be hard to tell from pictures)

Comment: It is Sand Green. Olive Green is quite different and is darker.